# Where is my Laravel Administrator page?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I am a first time Laravel user.
I have installed laravel & the administrator via

```
$ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
$ laravel new Project
$ cd Project
$ composer require "frozennode/administrator: 5.*"
>> added the provider as the docs say
$ php artisan vendor:publish
```

How can I now access a basic view of the admin interface?
Accessing http://example.com/Project/public/index.php?admin leads to a blank page.

I need to create a view of a database table that is already populated.

Comment: @Jan: what that supposed to be?

Comment: Admittedly, just a silly joke (it came to my mind when I first read the title of the question - it is a game for US children). Concerning your question, have you read the [frozennode documentation](http://administrator.frozennode.com/docs/configuration) ?

Comment: Yes, but it assumes i actually know how laravel works. They tell how to configure basic things in the app, and then go on showing some screenshots and how to configure the views. I need to access them first

Comment: are you able to see welcome screen if you navigate to /

Comment: The author offers [a detailed video on vimeo](https://vimeo.com/64693369) as well.

Comment: @KhanShahrukh: as in http://example.com/Project/public/ ? No, Still a blank page. If you are referring to / as the webserver root, i have other apps there, and have not setup pretty-url's. I dont need them at this point.

Comment: did you chmod 755 or 777 your storage folder and public folder(in case the first doesn't help)

Comment: @KhanShahrukh: thx, I can now see the Laravel 5 text:) still no auth page

Answer (score 0):

*"Where is my Laravel Administrator page?"* You can navigate `/vendor/encore/laravel-admin/resources/views`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Please check if you have following files in your installation:

**Resources folder:**

*app.blade.php

welcome.blade.php

home.blade.php*

**app/http/Controller folder:**

*Controller.php

HomeController.php

WelcomeController.php*

If No:
Create in app/Controller/ new Controller with name WelcomeController.php
In app/Http/routes.php check if Route to welcome blade exist.
if No add follow:

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

In your WelcomeController add following:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
```

**For Admin page:**

Ok, the same procedure only change following: 
add Controller *HomeController.php*

add to route:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index');
```

Create in resourcess/view: 
admin.blade.php with your html code.

in your HomeController add:

```
    public function index() { 
return view('admin'); 
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: The welcome view is there, it's working (after chmod, as @Khan suggested). I want to see the administrator page, not the default page though.

Comment: Ok, the same procedure only change following:
add Controller HomeController.php
add to route:
Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index');

Create in resourcess/view:
admin.blade.php with your html code.

in your HomeController add:
public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }

Comment: Yess, but how does Administrator help with that? I need to be able to see somethign like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/master/examples/images/menu.png, that why I installed Administrator in the first place. If I'd be going to build my own interface from scratch I would only need Laravel

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Comment: have you read the installation guide?
http://administrator.frozennode.com/docs/installation

Comment: I have followed https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator It seems like github exaples how to use with Laravel 5, and the official website explains Laravel 4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93045/discussion-between-quamis-and-crni).